# Which fresh herbs goes well with an omelette?

Tags: eggs, spices, herbs, omelette

I'm playing around with omelettes, and was wondering which fresh herbs (and fresh spices) are commonly used in omlettes?  Also, are there some that are often avoided? I'm looking for personal experiences from people who like to experiment.

Comment: I'm sorry, but flavor parings aren't considered on topic here as they're largely a matter of opinion. See our "[on topic](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" page for more info.

Comment: See also http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/a/1743/1672

Comment: Oh, and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/67451/how-can-i-find-flavors-that-pair-well-with-a-given-ingredient !

Comment: Hi Baard,  I've made a few changes that I hope will make your question no longer run afoul of the rules.  If you don't like my changes, please feel free to undo them.

Comment: @JS. Thanks for trying to help out, but I don't think details of phrasing like that matter. We're not being picky about exactly how you ask, we just don't generally do "what goes with X?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain omelette: parsely and chives.

I'd be careful with woody, stalky herbs like rosemary; not because of the taste but because I don't want to chew on the hard pieces. Keep in mind that the omelette does not get cooked as long as other dishes where these work well.

Then depending on the filling: anything with cream and fish may work with dill. Italian style with sage and thyme. (Not herbs, but for completeness: Paprika with mushrooms and red wine. Garlic with fried onions.)