# How to marinate tofu for my mint & lemon juice couscous salad?

Tags: marinade, ingredient-selection, salad, tofu

How could I marinate my tofu such that it fits well with my couscous salad which is seasoned with mint and lemon juice, and also contains cucumber, tomato and bell pepper and onions?

Comment: Are you asking what the method would be to marinate the tofu? Or are you asking what ingredients/flavors would go with the other ingredients in the salad,  which would probably be closed as primarily opinion based.

Comment: @DebbieM both, actually, I have no idea what ingredients to use.

Comment: @DebbieM. I thought "ingredient selection" is [on topic](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Flavor pairing is off topic. Ingredient selection is something like "Which apple will stay firmer when baked in a pie?"

Comment: I would add that we have a [canonical question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/67451/how-can-i-find-flavors-that-pair-well-with-a-given-ingredient) providing resources for finding flavor pairings.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who makes their own tofu, I would season it with citrus juice or zest during the coagulation process. Since you are using store bought I would soak it in lemon juice and toasted sesame oil 8 hours before lightly frying it. You could also use a sesame oil and ponzu marinade.